# I'm the only one who feels hot in my office, what can I do?

Tags: work-environment, temperature

I work in Tokyo where they keep the office on about 26C (78.8F), which is normal according to Japanese standards. I come from Louisiana where we keep our house on 68F (20C). Wearing long pants is not a rule but everybody here does it. There's about 100 employees on my floor and I'm the only one who ever seems to be burning up.

What can I do about this? Even if I wear shorts my back and legs get damp. And my chair is already a mesh like chair with holes all through out it to allow airflow.

Comment: Patience helps.  Keep at it and your internal thermostat will adjust.  As long as you're not keeping your home in Tokyo at 20C too.

Comment: **Remember not to accept an answer too quickly.** [You might want to wait 24 to 48 hours before accepting to give other people a chance to give you a better answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/260382). A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're the odd one out, the burden falls on you to adapt.

- Get a personal desk fan to keep yourself ventilated.
- Dress for the temperature. Lightweight, loose clothing that is meant for warm environments like linen will make a big difference.
- If there is a cooler part of the office, ask to move your workstation there.

Comment: Good advice in general.  I would add that when I lived on the East Coast, what helped me adapt the best was to do some outdoor exercise in the heat every spring.  Not so much I dropped from heat exhaustion, but enough to feel very, very hot.  Only a couple episodes went a long way to resetting my internal thermostat to find the regular ambient temperature more reasonable.  And of course avoid any colder a/c at home, if you have it, as that totally invalidates any efforts to acclimate.

Answer (score 0):

You mention legwear (shorts vs. pants) and a mesh chair, which are a good start of things to look at.  Additional things to try would be:

- Different shoes and socks (feet have a [disproportionate impact on perceived body temperature](http://www.stuff.co.nz/science/7205016/Ask-a-scientist-Feet-keep-us-warm))
- Different clothing materials - linen as MackM mentioned, or wool (woven thin, it's actually a comfortable warm-weather material)
- If acceptable to your coworkers, a personal fan as MackM mentioned; try it in different locations, you might find that e.g. blowing on your feet and calves is more effective in reducing discomfort than blowing on your arms.